# Example fields are missing when generating code from openapi

Tags: java, maven, swagger, openapi-generator

Please tell me this is the first time I’m writing openApi documentation and generating code from it.
Almost everything worked as I planned, but I can substitute an example in the response, which returns the string type.
This is an example of my endpoint description:

```
  /getDictionaries:
get:
  tags:
    - Dictionaries
  description: extrep_mdm.spk_get_rf_mrf_citizens
  operationId: getSpkDictionary
  responses:
    '200':
      description: Successful operation
      content:
        application/json:
          schema:
            type: string
          examples:
            someExample:
              $ref: '#/components/examples/myExample'
```

And this is a component of the example:

```
 components:
   examples:
     myExample:
       summary: Test
       value: 'test'
```

If I look through the swageer-editor, then everything looks correct and the example is filled in:
[image]
But when I generate code in my application, there is no block about examples:
[image]
And, accordingly, nothing changes in the swagger interface:
[image]

From this I concluded that I did not configure openapi-generator-maven-plugin correctly, here is how it is configured for me:

```
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
            <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>6.6.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-rest-api</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <generatorName>spring</generatorName>
                        <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/openapi.yaml</inputSpec>
                        <apiPackage>org.example.swagger.controller</apiPackage>
                        <modelPackage>org.example.swagger.model</modelPackage>
                        <generateSupportingFiles>true</generateSupportingFiles>
                        <generateApiDocumentation>true</generateApiDocumentation>
                        <generateApis>true</generateApis>
                        <generateModels>true</generateModels>
                        <configOptions>
                            <interfaceOnly>true</interfaceOnly>
                            <dateLibrary>java8-localdatetime</dateLibrary>
                        </configOptions>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

But I just can’t figure out where the error is, please tell me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenAPI Generator doesn't support `examples` (plural) in responses:

https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/16051

A possible workaround is to update your response definition to use a single `example`. Note that this `example` must be an inline value and cannot use $refs.

```yaml
  responses:
    '200':
      description: Successful operation
      content:
        application/json:
          schema:
            type: string
          example: 'test'  # Response-level example
```

or

```yaml
      content:
        application/json:
          schema:
            type: string
            example: 'test'  # schema-level example
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Tell me one more nuance or send me an article where I can read about it. As I understand it, by default the generator does not include the “info” and “servers” blocks in swagger-ui. I would still like to see them there)